# [python]Writing a data file using numbers 1-10

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
dataFile = open("temp1", "w")
for line in range(11):
    dataFile.write(line)
dataFile.close()
```

This is what i have so far, but i keep getting a error when i run this code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "datafile print liines.py", line 3, in <module>
        dataFile.write(line)
    TypeError: expected a character buffer object
    >Exit code: 1
```

I would like this code to write a dataFile using the number 1-10, so i was thinking using a for loop and range would do this, but im not sure how to write it to a file one number per line.

I know python has a 'w' command that creates a opens a file.

Can anyone give me some suggestion on why im getting this error and how i can write this to a datafile?

Comment: On a side note, you should check out [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for writing to files - it's more readable and handles closing for you - even when exceptions occur.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a string to the file not an integer.

`range(11)` returns a list of integers:

```
In [1]: range(11)
Out[1]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Try changing line 3 to the following:

```
dataFile.write(str(line))
```

You can add a newline so that the resulting text in the file appears more readable:

```
dataFile.write('%s\n' % line))
```

Comment: can you explain i little more what the inside of the () is doing here :   ('%s\n' % line))  "

Comment: @user1370982 The string in `line` replaces the string placeholder `%s`. `%s\n` acts as a template. You can read more about string formatting [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dataFile = open("temp1", "w")
for line in range(11):
    dataFile.write("%s\n" % line)
dataFile.close()
```

Which produces a file with this in

```
0
1
2
3
4
5 
6
7
8
9
10
```

You can only use strings as a parameter to `write`