# Python: writing a data file with three columns of integers

Tags: python

The code I am working with is:

```
fout = open('expenses.0.col', 'w')  
for line in lines:
  words = line.split()
  amount = amountPaid(words)
  num = nameMonth(words)
  day = numberDay(words)
  line1 = amount, num, day
  fout.write(line1)
fout.close()
```

There is a file that you cannot see that the line in lines is pulling from which runs just fine. There are 100 lines within lines. When writing this last bit of code the goal is to get 100 lines of three columns which consist of the values: amount, num, and day. All three of these values are integers.

I have seen similar questions asked such as [[python]Writing a data file using numbers 1-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420931/pythonwriting-a-data-file-using-numbers-1-10), and I get the same error as that example. My problem is applying dataFile.write("%s\n" % line) to my case with three numbers in each line. Should be a quick 1 line of code fix.

Comment: The answer in there completely explains you the problem. Argument line1 should be a string. Create a string from your three variables and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `line1` is a tuple - of numbers (I assume the functions `amountPaid(), nameMonth(), numberDay()` all return an integer or float).

You could do one of two things:

- have these functions return the numbers as strings values
- or cast the return values as string i.e.:  `amount =
  str(amountPaid(words))`

Once these values are strings you can simply do:

```
line1 = amount, num, day, '\n'
fout.write(''.join(line1))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `int(amountPaid(words))` is not casting to a string.

Comment: The new-line is missing. And `str.join` can only merge strings, so the three variables can't be integers and would need to be comverted to a string before joining.

Answer (score 0):

use the print statement/function rather than the write method.

Answer (score 0):

```
line1 = amount, num, day
fout.write("{}\n".format("".join(str(x) for x in line1)))
```